# Why is categorize a String[ ] in apache opennlp 1.8 instead of a String?

Tags: java, document, opennlp

Why does the input of  `myCategorizer.categorize();` have to be a `String[]` in apache opennlp 1.8 instead of a `String` like in version 1.5 of apache OpenNLP?

Because I want to check separate strings instead of a array?

```
 public void trainModel() 
    {
        InputStream dataIn = null;
        try 
        {;
            dataIn = new FileInputStream("D:/training.txt");
            ObjectStream lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, "UTF-8");
            ObjectStream sampleStream = new DocumentSampleStream(lineStream);
            // Specifies the minimum number of times a feature must be seen
            int cutoff = 2;
            int trainingIterations = 30;
            model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("NL", sampleStream, cutoff,trainingIterations);


        } 

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        finally 
        {
            if (dataIn != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    dataIn.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


public void classifyNewTweet(String tweet) 
{
    DocumentCategorizerME myCategorizer = new DocumentCategorizerME(model);
    double[] outcomes = myCategorizer.categorize(tweet);
    String category = myCategorizer.getBestCategory(outcomes);

    if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) 
    {
        System.out.println("The tweet is positive :) ");
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("The tweet is negative :( ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the days of OpenNLP 1.5, The first thing the DocumentCatagorizer did was to tokenize your string into words.  At first, this might appear to be easy, however, you might prefer to use the maximum entropy tokenizer instead of the default WhitespaceTokenizer.  The tokenizer can have a large effect on the classification.  Changing the API to allow the user to pick the tokenizer of his/her choice alleviates the problem.  Just add

```
Tokenizer tokenizer = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE;
...
String[] tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(tweet);
double[] outcomes = myCategorizer.categorize(tweet);
...
```

That should resolve your problem.  You could also use a statistical tokenizer (see TokenizerME) or the SimpleTokenizer.